# Spring 4 @cacheable annotation : how add properties for custom key generator?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ehcache

In my Java project, I migrate spring to -> 4.3.4 and I migrate ehcache-spring-annotation to http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache.

I have problems to define properties of my cache customkeygenerator :

```
 @Cacheable(value = "cacheDAO", keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator(name = "CacheKeyGenerator",
        properties = { @Property(name = "useReflection", value = "true"),
                       @Property(name = "checkforCycles", value = "true"),
                       @Property(name = "includeMethod", value = "false") })
```

it seems not possible to define useReflection, checkForCycles or includeMethod by a @keyGenerator annotation.

Could you help me to config it please ? how it's work with spring 4 ?
Please tell me if you don't understand my ask.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) that does not seem possible inline. However, it is pretty trivial to have specific beans configured from the same key generator but with different property values mapped to different bean names. And then you reference the exact one in the `@Cacheable` annotation.